# W/System.err(21922): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have checkboxlist where the user selectes some items I am envloping his selecting in json format then I am firing the json string from the alarmManager to the GetLLRD class. Currently I have problem with receiving intent in the  `IntentService` class since I am getting intent in the OnHandleIntent not every 60 second but for various  time as it shows in the output below.

I have tried it with the IntentReceiver there I am getting the output as scheduled. Therefor, I want to start my `HttpUrlConenction` from the onReceive method in the `IntentReceiver`. I have tried it but I am getting warning like `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` where I dont have any problem with the internet conenction since I have another AsynTask classes which sending and getting requests to/from the server in the app.

Can I send HttpUtlConenction request from BroadcastReceiver and what I am doing wrong?

**Some of the output:**

```
07-07 19:39:06.805: I/System.out(7534): test from the onHandleIntent{"selected":[6,9]}
07-07 19:39:19.417: I/System.out(7534): test from the onHandleIntent{"selected":[6]}
07-07 19:39:19.417: I/System.out(7534): test from the onHandleIntent{"selected":[6,9]}
07-07 19:39:30.378: I/System.out(7534): test from the onHandleIntent{"selected":[6,9]}
07-07 19:39:45.323: I/System.out(7534): test from the onHandleIntent{"selected":[6,9]}
```

**MainActivity class:**

```
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            IntentReceiver.class);
                    intent.putExtra("json_data", json);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                            getApplicationContext(), 3, intent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                            System.currentTimeMillis(), 60 * 1000,
                            pendingIntent);
                    // cal.getTimeInMillis()
                    startService(intent);
```

**GetLLRD class:**

```
public class GetLLRD extends IntentService {

    public GetLLRD() {
        super("IntentService");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        String jSONString = intent.getStringExtra("json_data");
        System.out.println("test from the onHandleIntent" + jSONString);
        if(jSONString != null){

            System.out.println("Test");
        }

    }
}
```

**IntentReceiver:**

```
public class IntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            String action = intent.getStringExtra("json_data");

            if (!action.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("test from IntentReiceier" + action);

             BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {

                URL myUrl = new URL(
                        "https://apple-bustracker.rhcloud.com/webapi/test");

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl
                        .openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                conn.connect();
                // create data output stream
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                        conn.getOutputStream());
                // write to the output stream from the string
                wr.writeBytes(jsonString);

                wr.close();

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        conn.getInputStream()));
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");

                }

                try {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<ItemDTO>>() {
                    }.getType();
                    data = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), listType);
                } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                for (ItemDTO itemDTO : data) {
                    double latitude = itemDTO.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = itemDTO.getLongitude();
                    int route = itemDTO.getRoute();
                    String direction = itemDTO.getDirection();
                    System.out.println("test" + latitude + ", " + longitude + ", "
                            + ", " + route + ", " + direction);

                }


            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: where are you registering your `IntentReceiver`?

Comment: @emerssso: I have registered it in the manifest.xml

Comment: I have registered it like this `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), TypAutoStart, aiAutostart, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);` before but I changed it to getService to try it with IntentService

Comment: also currently it is registered as getBroadcast().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I send HttpUtlConenction request from BroadcastReceiver

No. `onReceive()` is called on the main application thread, and you should not do disk I/O or network I/O on the main application thread. Move that HTTP code into another `IntentService`, and call `startService()` on that `IntentService` from `onReceive()`.

Comment: I have tried this solution before but I received the intent to quick in the onHandleIntent method in the  IntentService class?

Comment: @light: "but I received the intent to quick in the onHandleIntent method in the IntentService class?" -- I have no idea what that means.

Comment: @ CommonsWare: Yes I had this cas yesterday but it worked after I duninstalled the app then run and published it again.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior in you `IntentReceiver` is being executed in the main thread. Network access must be done from a background thread, so it should be moved to a background thread, probably via an `IntentService`. For example:

```
 public class IntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent intentForService = new Intent(context, MyIntentService.class);

        intentForService.setAction(intent.getAction());
        intentForService.setData(intent.getData());
        intentForService.replaceExtras(intent.getExtras());

        context.startService(intentForService);
    }
 }
```

And then

```
 public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {
     //You'll need some boilerplate like the constructor for this new class

     @Override
     protected void onHandleIntent(final Intent intent) {
          //Your current behavior in IntentReceiver goes here
     }
 }
```

Comment: Is there any explaniation for this behaviour of IntentService. I have commented the lines of the alarmManger but I am still getiitng the output of the seleced Items of the checkboxlist int the MainActivity? how can I stop the IntentService class from processing?

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html for details on Intent services. I'm not sure what your second question is.